# how to use global variable with phonegap navigator.notification.confirm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, global-variables

i have this situation:

```
<a href="#" onClick="submitNotification(1);">click1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="submitNotification(2);">click2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="submitNotification(3);">click3</a>

function submitNotification(cdata){
    navigator.notification.confirm(
            'do you like '+cdata+' option ',
            submit,
            'notice',
            'Yes,No'
    );

function submit(button){    
    if (button == 1){
        alert(id); //or alert(cdata);
    } else if (button == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

so, i click on a link, `1` or `2` ... gets send to `submitNotification` where i get a message: `do you like 1 option` or `do you like 2 option` or ... depending on what link i click.

this function calls `submitVote` and sends `button` var to it somehow. `yes` means `1` and `no` means `2`.

the problem is that i cant get `id` or `cdata` from the original link. actually they came as value `3` (the last link).

i use to do:

```
function submitNotification(cdata){
    navigator.notification.confirm(
            'do you like '+cdata+' option ',
            submit(cdata),
            'notice',
            'Yes,No'
    );

function submit(id){    
    if (button == 1){
        alert(id);
    } else if (button == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

in this case i get the `id` alert but the button values are not available.

Any ideas how to get access to that `id` or `cdata`, whatever var is available? Is there a way to send both `button` and `cdata` vars to the `submit` function

note: the links get created in a `$.each` loop.

thanks

Comment: You changed the code while I wrote an answer. Now I'll write it again to answer your question :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps (after all the code rewriting :)).

Notice that both `submitNotification` and `submit` are separate functions (not nested in) and var `buttonClicked` is defined in global scope.

```
var buttonClicked = 0;

function submitNotification(cdata){
    buttonClicked = cdata;

    navigator.notification.confirm(
            'do you like '+cdata+' option ',
            submit,
            'notice',
            'Yes,No'
    );
 }

function submit(button){    
    if (buttonClicked === 1){
      doWhatYouWant(); // .. but think about the Omen
    }
}
```

Comment: i get `result of expression this.setAttribute [undefined] is not a function`, also in that loop i get all my links attribute, but i only need the one i clicked on

Comment: ok, so ,  my loop i have this `<a href="#" onClick="submitNotification('+id+');">click1</a>` u think i should create a `var newId = id` and that will be available in my `submit function`?

Comment: success, that worked, i know this is fill up text, but what does it mean? `doWhatYouWant(); // .. but think about the Omen` ?? is it from a quote or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitNotification(cdata){
    navigator.notification.confirm(
            'do you like '+cdata+' option ',
            submit,
            'notice',
            'Yes,No'
    );

function submit(button){    
    if (button == 1){
        alert(id);
    } else if (button == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```